# asp.net 3.5 namespace of website?

Tags: asp.net, namespaces

im working on a asp.net 3.5 app. i am trying to reference a public class in another class, but the IDE can't find it. In .net 4.0 you can set the namespace of the website. i think i just need to add the namespace reference to point to the public class i'm trying to reference, but can't figure out what the "root" or "base" namespace is (or where to set it) in 3.5

public class user control:

```
Public Class dashboard_controls_registration
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
End Class
```

My Business Object:

```
Namespace BusinessLayer
    Public Class BusinessObject
        Public Function MakeControl() as String
             Dim ctl As dashboard_controls_registration = DirectCast(pageHolder.LoadControl("/controls/registration.ascx"), UserControl)
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

In the "MakeControl" function in the businesslayer.businessobject im trying to reference the control (a public class):

However, IDE is throwing an error that it's undefined. I would assume because it's not in the same namespace?

I would think that if i referenced the "dashboard_controls_registration" class with it's namespace it would work.. ie:

```
Dim ctl As namespace.dashboard_controls_registration = DirectCast(pageHolder.LoadControl("/controls/registration.ascx"), UserControl)
```

but I can't find a way in 3.5 to define the "root" namespace of the project.  IN 4.0 I use this exact code and it works fine.

Thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: If your project don't set an explicit namespace, it defaults to the name of your solution. Try that.

Comment: I tried that, no luck. Do you know where to set this?

Comment: Why is your business object creating usercontrols?

Comment: Dynamically creating string based on a control (used as a template) the string is used in emails, print previews, etc. The control is basically a template.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like a very odd way to do a simple template to me, but if it works I suppose. Are you dealing with more then one assembly/project you forgot to mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not set this project up as a web application. Once I did that, it worked fine.